# Jenkins,Docker,Kubernetes,AWS EKS: RUN npm install either hangs or produces EAI_AGAIN

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, kubernetes

First off, I am totally new to deploying CICD builds.

I started with a successful setup of Jenkins X on an AWS EKS Cluster via this 
[guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/continuous-delivery-eks-jenkins-x/#).

I am able to run the pipeline via GitHub and builds successfully on a normal jx quickstart.

Problems arose when I started pushing my node express application.

On an alpine node base, my dockerfile looked like this:

```
FROM node:10.15.3-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci --prod
FROM alpine:3.7
COPY --from=0 /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/
COPY --from=0 /usr/lib/libgcc* /usr/lib/libstdc* /usr/lib/
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=0 /app .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

And it terminated with an error:

```
Step 5/14 : RUN npm ci --prod
 ---> Running in c7f038a80dcc
[91mnpm[0m[91m ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
[0m[91mnpm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
[0m[91mnpm ERR![0m[91m request to https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-4.16.4.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
[0mtime="2019-03-28T08:26:00Z" level=fatal msg="build failed: building [community]: build artifact: The command '/bin/sh -c npm ci --prod' returned a non-zero code: 1"
```

I tried using a non alpine base and this was how it looked:

```
FROM node:10-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
ENV PORT 3000
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

But then, the problem was the build hangs (or is taking very long) when it hits the RUN npm install step.

I have scoured for possible answers and duplicate questions but to no avail. So I last resorted into asking it here.

I don't have an idea of what's going on honestly.

Comment: `getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org` - this shows clearly that the problem is with DNS resolution. Did you try to troubleshoot it using something like `dig`? E.g. what commands `dig registry.npmjs.org` and `dig registry.npmjs.org @8.8.8.8` return (install `dig` with `apk add bind-tools`, if required)? And share `/etc/resolv.conf`, please.

Comment: @VeeBee Did you manage to solve this? I have the same problem with EKS. But when I try to jump in the agent I can curl registry.npmjs.org. That's weird.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this issue by enabling docker bridge network when bootstrapping EKS worker nodes.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o xtrace
/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh --enable-docker-bridge true 'your-cluster-name'
```

More detail in this Github issue: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/issues/183